# API full path in unit tests

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

Is there any way to specify full path for url when i test APIs. Now i'm doing it in this way:

```
def test_product_types_retrieve(self):
    self.relative_path = '/api/api_product/'
    response = self.client.get(self.relative_path + 'product_types/')
```

I should add relative_path part to every single request, but i want to set it, for example in setUp function. Without self.relative_path i will get http://localhost:8000/product_types/ instead of http://localhost:8000/api/api_product/product_types/

My project structure is following, every api have its own urls.py with urlpatterns settings.

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnhJD.png)

Comment: Use [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) or [`reverse_lazy()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) function to populate the URLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this, you then set up the relative path in the setUp and call the api from call_api can pass args and kwargs through that.

Then if on a test you need a different relative_path you can just set it on that test and still call call_api.

```
class ExampleTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.relative_path = '/api/api_product/'

    def call_api(self, endpoint):
        return self.client.get(self.relative_path + endpoint)

    def test_product_types_retrieve(self):
        response = self.call_api('product_types/')

    def test_requires_different_path(self):
        self.relative_path = '/api/api_product/v1/'
        response = self.call_api('product_types/')
```